# What all web servers support HTML 5?

Tags: html

What all web servers support HTML 5 content? Do they have some config that allows to switch between HTML versions based on client browsers?

Comment: Yes, but don't do it. HTML5 is made to degrade for browsers that don't support it (namely IE).

Answer (score 2):

HTML 5 was explicitly designed to degrade gracefully in older browsers that do not understand it. As such, there's no need to serve different versions. You may or may not have to put in some client-side Javascript-based shims for some of the more advanced HTML 5 features, but there's no need to have several versions of the same HTML document.

Comment: I get the feeling you went through and downvoted everyone who actually answered his question. Either way, it IS important to serve compatable pages to people. If you have a HTML5 Canvas that needs to be Flash in HTML4, then what? It won't exactly degrade, you have to provide different versions.

Comment: @Dan You can look at my reputation history to see who I downvoted. And for your particular case, that fallback can and should be on the client. Use a *capability-based fallback* in your Javascript, instead of a user-agent based document switching.

Comment: I did not know that HTML4 browsers had a "doesHTML5work()" function.. What is it?

Comment: @Dan No, because HTML 5 isn't one particular thing: http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html#canvas

Comment: I know, I just mean, how can I find out if the browser I'm on supports the Canvas tag? I'm honestly out of the know on this one.

Comment: OH. Yes. Sorry, you linked to the Canvas specifically so I had no idea what the title was (it's too long to fit in its tab). Thanks, useful.

Answer (score -1):

You can determine the users browser agent in PHP or some other web-cgi, look it up in some giant array to determine if it's HTML5 compatible, and serve them a HTML5 page if so, HTML4 if not.

In pure HTML, browsers ignore elements they don't understand, but will treat it like it's not there, so you can use that for SOME tricks, but it's mostly done by serving a different page for HTML4/HTML5 browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Web servers would know client's browser by [Useragent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent).

And with browers' names and versions, the server can identify whether a client's browser

supports HTML5 or not.

With that information, you can dynamically change **DOCTYPE** in your page

Comment: Why would you? HTML 5 was designed to degrade gracefully for older browsers, no need to serve different versions.

Comment: @deceze I'm just suggesting a way to recognize a client's browser and set DOCTYPE depends on the browser information

Comment: Yes, but it's bad advise, whatever the OP asked. And I'm not even 100% certain what exactly the OP asked.

Comment: "User agent" actually **means** a browser.